# How can I collect all the Snow Globe Trading Cards with many restrictions on my account?

Tags: steam

Since I'm home for Christmas I was interested in buying some steam games to fill my library. My account was basically unused as I made it over 1 year ago with the same intentions but never got around to it. I'm at a new IP address and have changed my password as I forgot my original one.

Now I'm really getting into the steam community but am finding it hard to collect the snow globe trading cards. Because of this for some reason I'm not able to buy a $0.35 item on the market place yet I'm able to buy a $50.00 game? This limits me in so many different ways such as not being able to complete the steam community challenge. I could complete it a bit easier if they would fix the uploading videos from youtube option but theres already multiple questions on that. Even thought I might spend over $100 I already spent over $40 but only received 3 cards even after waiting more than 24 hours.

So in combination with a card every $10.00 spent and reaching level 5 I think I can receive all 10 cards to craft the badge but it's the ladder option that's the tricky part I need help with. Like... crafting badges is basically out of the question because you don't receive card drops for the whole set so you're forced to wait for a card booster pack which would most likely take longer than I have or trade for the remaining cards which is not an option for me.

So please post my options if any, or am I just forced to spend over $100.00.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "restrictions" you're saying you've got on your account do not match up with [what Steam call a "limited account"](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3330-IAGK-7663) - it is probably worth **[contacting Steam support](https://support.steampowered.com/newticket.php)** to discuss the issues you're having with the Steam store.

There are four methods of earning Snow Globe cards:

- Vote in the "Community's Choice" sale every 8 hours, for every three times you vote you get one card (that's one free card per day)

  [image]
- Buying games/software from Steam: for every $10 you spend on Steam you get a Snow Globe card
- Trading with other players on the Steam market
- Crafting other badges will result in a Snow Globe card for each badge crafted

One thing to note is that getting Snow Globes by voting for the "Community's Choice" sale requires that you be level 5 already.

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys, I will look into contacting steam support with my issue.

Comment: Note that I had to log out and back in of Steam community due to some alleged cookie issue - maybe that fixes things for you as well

Answer (score 3):

You will have to spend much more than $100 to get all 10 of the snow globe cards, as you will get cards randomly from buys. This means that you will end up with multiples of the same card, and not get any of the other cards you actually need. If all you can do is buy games, it will likely cost you a very large chunk of change if you want to max out the steam snow glow badge. It will likely take over $300 just to get level 1 badge. And the only way to get the foil badge would be to buy them from the marketplace, as they are so rare.

The only economical way to achieve your goal is to get Steam support to disable steam guard, or set up a new account, buy the cards you need, and trade them back to your main account.

Comment: Im not allowed to trade though?

Comment: Only due to changing your pass, it will last 2 weeks.

Comment: @DaftMau5 Don't forget that the cards won't go away either, so you can still trade them later on if you want.

Comment: The snow globe cards DO go away. Check the details about them on Steam. Once the event is over, the cards disappear forever. So you have a limited time to earn the badges. The gear that come along with it will be limited in number also, unless Steam decides to have them generated in yet another event, like their Summer 2014 sale.

Comment: @StarPilot When steam did their other card sale, I guess the summer sale? They are still in my inventory and are still there... It wasn't like that the years before but that was without the cards then.

Comment: @Lyrion They have *specifically* changed that.

Comment: @Lyrion see the event page at url: http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/snowglobefaq

Answer (score 0):

You can just purchase them; I put number 5 up today for $2.30. You don't have to spend over a hundred dollars.

Comment: [Is this an answer or are you asking us a question? I'm getting mixed signals?](http://youtu.be/vwczZLOmBhw)

Comment: Read the post, "With Restrictions"

Comment: Today, you can purchase the full set for about $1.50.